# Is it a security issue when you append a backend authentication token to a response URL?

Tags: security, oauth, jwt, google-oauth, django-authentication

I have implemented an OAuth flow where once users authenticate using google my Django backend creates a profile for them and also creates a JWT token for them to use to access some restricted API endpoints. The issue I'm currently having is how should I send the token to the frontend. Right now, I'm appending the token to the Frontend URL and redirecting the users to the frontend where the token is extracted from the URL and saved in local storage.
Is this a security issue and if so, how should I overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a frontend which talks to your own backend, then I would consider using plain-old sessions with cookies instead of JWTs. Unfortunately tokens are never safe in the browser. You shouldn't keep them in the local storage as they can be quite easily extracted form there by any malicious code. It is safer to keep the token in the memory, but a more sophisticated XSS would still be able to steal that token.

I was recently hosting a webinar were we talked about the security of handling tokens in the browser and why we think you should stick to sessions: https://curity.io/resources/webinars/hardening-single-page-app-security. You can also have a look at this great video which dives into more technical details of attacks on tokens in the browser: https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html

Still, if you want to stick to your solution a few things I would consider:

- send the token in the fragment part of the URL. Thanks to that the token will be a bit more safe (e.g. won't be saved in history, etc.)
- try to keep the token only in memory and avoid keeping it in local storage, unless losing the token isn't a real problem for your app (e.g. you don't have any personal information guarded by the token, etc.). I know that this requirement can be a bit more tricky when considering UX, as the token will be lost during a refresh of the page.